# How to login by ssh in Alpine Linux without passwords?

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, alpine-linux, termux

I'm using a Android cell phone. I write python program and run the program in Termux. But there some lib can't be installed or use in Android cell phone, sklearn and tensorflow for example. So I decided to try to use a docker container for my programing envirment.
I create a docker image and update it to docker-hub: zwdnet/mypython. Then I installed qemu in Termux，and installed Alpine Linux (alpine-virt-3.10.1-x86_64) in Termux. I followed this pages' method(It is a Chinese blog, not English):  https://stageguard.top/2019/08/15/run-docker-on-qemu-alpine/#1-Docker
After this, I use the command

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda python.img -boot c -m 4096 -netdev user,id=nde1,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 -device e1000,netdev=nde1,id=d-net1 -nographic &
```

start the alpine linux in back and

```
ssh root@localhost -p 2222
```

login. (After then I installed the docker and run the container success, that is another question.)
Now I want to login Apline linux without enter the passwords.
First I use

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

generate the key, and use

```
ssh-copy-id -i ./mykey.pub root@localhost -P 2222
```

to sent the pub key to the Apline linux and changed the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
At last I restarted the sshd service and logout.
But when I login again, It is ask me to enter the password again.
I thought maybe that is because I login in with root. So I login and create a new username, and repeat the ahead operators. But I failed. The ssh ask me to enter password again.
This is my mod of ~/.ssh and the key files.

```
$ssh zym@localhost -p 2222 "ls -la"
zym@localhost's password:
total 20
drwxr-sr-x    3 1000     zym           4096 May 16 15:04 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 16 14:44 ..
-rw-------    1 1000     zym            251 May 16 15:04 .ash_history
drwx------    2 1000     zym           4096 May 16 14:56 .ssh
-rw-------    1 root     zym            883 May 16 15:04 .viminfo
$ ssh zym@localhost -p 2222 "ls -la .ssh"
zym@localhost's password:
total 12
drwx------    2 1000     zym           4096 May 16 14:56 .
drwxr-sr-x    3 1000     zym           4096 May 16 15:04 ..
-rw-------    1 root     zym            571 May 16 14:56 authorized_keys
```

and this is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
# $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
# Feel free to re-enable these if your use case requires them.
AllowTcpForwarding no
GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
# X11Forwarding no
# AllowTcpForwarding no
# PermitTTY no
# ForceCommand cvs server
```

The login information is

```
$ ssh zym@localhost -p 2222 -v
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:2222 as 'zym'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Vwx+lpRpyl04g5gaO73Es9C1IslCcD7f9CUfBFyi96M
debug1: Host '[localhost]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:l/1hMa3CC1MHkHsJT6R7CRZJzYEXU
debug1: Will attempt key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2->
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:l/1hMa3CC1MHkHsJT6R7CRZJzU
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
zym@localhost's password:
```

I copyed the mykey and mykey.pub to /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/ , no use.
Could you please help me to see how to sovle this problem? Thanks!
I'm a Chinese and my English is poor. Please forgive me for the words errors.

Thanks @MarcoLucidi ,but the -i in ssh dose not work.

```
$ ssh -i ./mykey -p 2222 zym@localhost -v
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ./mykey type 0
debug1: identity file ./mykey-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:2222 as 'zym'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Vwx+lpRpyl04g5gaO73Es9C1IslCcD7f9CUfBFyi96M
debug1: Host '[localhost]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: ./mykey RSA SHA256:4rVLy6uWZoHmCMqYYyaASSV2iaoIdIbvIDtA1EBNuW0 explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2->
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ./mykey RSA SHA256:4rVLy6uWZoHmCMqYYyaASSV2iaoIdIbvIDtA1EBNuW0 explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
zym@localhost's password:
```

Comment: you can "force" the use of a specific key using the `-i` option, try `ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey -p 2222 zym@localhost`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just tried but it seemed not work.             $ ssh -i ./mykey -p 2222 zym@localhost
zym@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
zym@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
zym@localhost's password:
zym@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password.
I put the full output in my question.

Comment: please make sure that your public key is stored inside `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the user you are trying to login with (`zym`)

Comment: `drwxr-sr-x    3 1000     zym           4096 May 16 15:04 .` What UID is zym? Why is this line showing 1000 for the UID instead of "zym"?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi I just check it.  The public key in stored inside authorized_keys.                      $ cat mykey.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDbOULZS8unYCDJt
$ ssh zym@localhost -p 2222 "cat ~/.ssh/authorized_k"
zym@localhost's password:
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDbOULZS8unYCDJt
$

Comment: @Kenster In /etc/passwd?      zym:x:0:0:Linux User,,,:/home/zym:/bin/ash      I created zym when I login with root. Then I changed the uid from 1000 to 0, so I can run docker without type sudo or change to root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated in a comment that this user "zym" has UID 0. You also show that zym's home directory and `.ssh` directory are owned by UID 1000:

```
drwxr-sr-x    3 1000     zym           4096 May 16 15:04 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 16 14:44 ..
-rw-------    1 1000     zym            251 May 16 15:04 .ash_history
drwx------    2 1000     zym           4096 May 16 14:56 .ssh
```

The OpenSSH server [enforces strict permissions on the *authorized_keys* file](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#FILES):

> *~/.ssh/authorized_keys*
>       Lists the public keys (DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519, RSA) that can be used for logging in as this user. The format of this file is described above. The content of the file is not highly sensitive, but the recommended permissions are read/write for the user, and not accessible by others.
>
> If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory are writable by other users, then the file could be modified or replaced by unauthorized users. In this case, sshd will not allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to “no”.

The actual permissions-checking performed by sshd is complicated. But basically it checks for two things:

1. The *authorized_keys* file must be owned by the user logging in, and it must not be group- or world-writable.
2. The directory containing *authorized_keys*, the *.ssh* directory, and the home directory must be owned by root or the user logging in, and must not be group- or world-writable.

The OpenSSH server is probably ignoring your *authorized_keys* file because these requirements aren't being met. You're trying to log in as a user with UID 0, while the authorized_keys file, .ssh directory, and home directory are owned by a different UID.

You can fix this by making the UIDs match. Either set "zym" to have UID 1000, or change zym's home directory and the files contained there to be owned by zym's actual UID of 0.

Alternately, you can disable this permissions check by setting [StrictModes](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#StrictModes) to "no" in sshd_config on the server and restarting sshd.

Comment: Thank you. I try to change zym uid back to 1000, no use. There is no SecureModes item in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config, I added it and restarted sshd service, I got a error.    I deleted it and found a item named StrictModes, I uncommented it and changed the value to no. Then restarted sshd and try again.Now it works! I didn't need to type password!(but still need with -i  ./mykey when run ssh. )Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, the parameter is StrictModes.

Answer (score 12):

i discovered that alpine linux image is shipped with a root user that has no password set yet. And for some reason it seems like not having a password set for root prevents the public key authentication from succeeding when trying to ssh on root account.

try setting a password to root user: ex:

```
echo 'root:dummy_passwd'|chpasswd
```

and then retry:

```
shh root@<ip_address>
```

now the command should work with the public key authentication. don't ask me why.

note: i discovered that because i could connect to a normal user session but not to root session with the same sshd_config, on the same machine, and with the same authorized_keys file (with correct permissions and correct ownership). that was the only thing i could think of and it made the difference.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me when using Alpine on Docker. Thanks a ton.

Comment: This worked for me. This should be reported as a bug in alpine linux.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me. Also, from my practice, `PasswordAuthentication yes` must be set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, at least for OpenSSH_8.2p1.

Answer (score 2):

After trying to disable my root user's password with `passwd -l`, or by directly setting the password hash to `!` in `/etc/shadow`, I was surprised to find my attempts to log in via ssh key rejected with "User root not allowed because account is locked" reported in `/var/log/messages`.

Based on guidance from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193131/353183, I changed the password hash in `/etc/shadow` from `!` to `*`, and that let me log in successfully.

Hashes beginning with an exclamation point signify a locked user, and OpenSSH rejects logins for locked users even when they use an authorized key. The asterisk still disables password logins by serving as an impossible-to-match hash, but it does not mark the account as locked. For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211719/2402324.

Comment: This was my issue, except my root ssh-key login worked while non-root did not. My cloud provider had asked for an initial root password, but my subsequent non-root user creation scripts didn't set passwords. I had never hit this issue in Ubuntu, but I did when trying Alpine, so maybe that's relevant.